# PHP Regular Expression for Number, Comma, Undersocre, Slash, Hyphen and Space

Tags: php, regex

I need a string which consists of some numbers, comma, undersocre, slash, hyphen and space.

I am almost ok. Here is my code so far.

```
$regex = '#^[0-9-_,/\s]+$#';
if(preg_match($regex, $string)){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

But I want to contain at least 4 digit within 0 to 9.

for example,
These are the values I want to valid:

```
09-12345678
123, 456, 789
12/ 34/ 56
```

These are the values I don't want to valid:

```
1,2
3/5/6
7-8-9
```

So, I tried like this.

```
$regex = '#^[0-9-_,/\s]{4,100}$#';
```

And,

```
$regex = '#^[0-9{4,100}-_,/\s]+$#';
```

But they are not true too.
How can I do?

Comment: `^(?=(?:.*\d){4})[0-9-_,/\s]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead based regex:

```
~^(?=(?:\D*\d){4})[-0-9_,/\s]+$~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA2fY6/1)

- `(?=(?:\D*\d){4})` is lookahead to assert presence of at least 4 digits in input.
- Also important is to keep hyphen at start or end in character class `[...]`

Comment: For OP: Revo's comment has `-` in middle which is not correct. And \`D*` is more efficient that `.*`. @Jan `\w` will also match `[a-zA-Z]` which wasn't included in OP's character class.

Comment: Although I copied that set from question, a `-` in middle of a character set does not make problem when is immediately preceded by another valid range. So it works (OP confirmed already). But I am sure `\D*` is much more efficient and I accept that part.